# Set an `UIImageView` to not highlighted on a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
@interface FavouriteCell : UITableViewCell

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *selectIcon;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *favName;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL checked;

+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end
```

On `selectIcon` I set two images from normal and highlighted. When I do `cell.checked = !selected;` on `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` it works perfectly.

But when I try to reset every selected cell on `clearSelectedFavourites:`, it doesn't work.

```
@interface FavViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
@private
    NSMutableArray* _favsSelected;
    BOOL* _isOnEditingMode;
}

// ######### FavViewController implementation ##############

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Favoritos", @"Favoritos");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav"];

        _favsSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _isOnEditingMode = NO;

    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"FavCell";

    FavouriteCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FavouriteCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _favCell;
        self.favCell = nil;
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.favName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);

    if (tableView.isEditing)
    {
        BOOL selected = NO;

        if ((_favsSelected != nil) && ([_favsSelected count] > 0))
            selected = ([_favsSelected indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound);

        FavouriteCell* cell =
            (FavouriteCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(cell.checked ? @"Yes" : @"No");
        cell.checked = !selected;

        if (selected)
            [_favsSelected removeObject:indexPath];
        else
            [_favsSelected addObject:indexPath];
    }
}

- (IBAction)editFavList:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"edit button clicked!");
    if ([_favList isEditing])
    {
        [self clearSelectedFavourites];
        [_favList setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonEdit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [_favList setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (void)clearSelectedFavourites
{
    for(int index = 0; index < [_favsSelected count]; index++)
    {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[_favsSelected objectAtIndex:index];

        FavouriteCell* cell = (FavouriteCell*)[self tableView:_favList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.checked = NO;
    }

    [_favsSelected removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(FavouriteCell *)cell
          atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = nil;

    object = [self.favListFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.favName.text = [[object valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}
```

**Do you know why?**

I have tried to set `selectIcon` to not hightlighted manually, but it doesn't work, and that code if the latest test I did.

I have also tested this: `[cell setHighlighted:NO];` on `clearSelectedFavourites:` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of cell.checked = NO, try with [cell setHighlighted:NO];

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In FavouriteCell class, implement this method, where write [self setHighlighted:boolValue]; [myImageView setHighlighted:boolValue];  - Same like, overriding the existing setHighlighted method

Comment: Why should `cell.checked = NO;` change the image? Do you have a custom setter that replaces the image?

Comment: @EliGanem No, I set on Interface Builder an image on UIImageView for highlighted state.

Comment: Habe you reloaded the table after calling clearSelectedFavourites method?

Comment: @Flappy Ok, the error was that I don't reload the table. How can I do to do the reload after the animation ends on `clearSelectedFavourites`?

Comment: @VansFannel Make sure that you're using the iOS 6 version of any function... specifically `setHighlighted:` is deprecated, and has been replaced with `setHighlighted:animated:`. I don't know whether it will make a difference, but better to try with the proper function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing us your custom `[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];` function, so I cannot know what's going on.

However a few things first:

The cells on the TableView are being reused.
So you cell select state needs to be set every time for each cell.

Also on your `clearSelectedFavourites` function, you are getting a reference to all selected cells, then clear their selection, which is pointless, because the cells are going to be reused.

You only need to loop through the visible `UITableView` cells and change their selection status, then clear your _favsSelected array...

```
- (void)clearSelectedFavourites
{

    NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
    for (FavouriteCell *cell in cells)
    {
        cell.checked = NO;
        //might not be needed, or might be needed
        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    [_favsSelected removeAllObjects];
}
```

Finally on your `configureCell` function, you should check if the cell should be checked or not, based on your `_favsSelected` array entries and just select it or not.

**Edit**

In your `configureCell` function you should check if the cell needs to be checked or not:

```
- (void)configureCell:(FavouriteCell *)cell
          atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = nil;

    object = [self.favListFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.favName.text = [[object valueForKey:@"name"] description];
    cell.checked = [_favsSelected containsObject:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Added configureCell:cell method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
[tbl beginUpdates];
```

/* call you method with animation */

```
[tbl endUpdates];

[tbl reloadData];
```